# Retrieving parameters from a custom URL in TideSDK

Tags: macos, url-scheme, tidesdk

I'm putting together a desktop application in TideSDK and am having some trouble finding the parameters passed to the application via a custom launch URL.

The application launches when the appropriate protocol is invoked (call it aaa://), but I haven't been able to figure out how to grab the URL string. I read a couple of threads that suggested I could get the string with the Ti.API.application.getArguments() call, but it returns something odd (see below).

```
// launch application with aaa://some_args_here
var args = Ti.API.application.getArguments();
// returns (StaticBoundList) [ /path/to/app, "-psn_0_721072", ]
```

I'm not completely surprised that this doesn't seem to work, as the API documentation says the getArguments method returns a list of command line arguments.

Any insight as to how to access the launch URL would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that there's currently an "official" way to do this, so I came up with my own solution that seems to work pretty well (though currently its only implemented for OSX).

Searching through the TideSDK source, I found the place where the native application delegate is created. I added a URL launch handler in the app delegate, which stores the launch URL in a new app delegate member, and connected it to the API with a binding in Ti.UI.

If anybody else is interested in this functionality, or have insights as to how to accomplish this task for Windows, please get in touch!

Answer (score 1):

have a look at window.location.search

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Comment: This returns information about the link that the SDK launches the application with (the app:// protocol) as opposed to the protocol that was used to trigger the launch of the application through a web browser (ie Safari). I manually edited the application's Info.plist to add a custom url scheme -- is there a right way to add the custom scheme?

Comment: ah gotcha. sorry for the confusion. I dont think there is a 'right way' yet to add a custom protocol. How you are doing it is probably the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have your problem, just want to say the following function works fine for me.

> var args = Ti.API.application.getArguments();

is it possible this is the problem of the urlprotocl registry?

my url protocol is set by this : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914#app_ex)

thus the value in "Command" is

> "C:\YOUR_APP_FOLDER\YOURAPP.exe" "%1"

tested on win7 and winxp, 
both successfully get the arguments.